# Как создать массив объектов в одну строку?

Tags: java

Имеется объект типа `Object`, который принимает одно значение типа `int`.

Как создать массив объектов `Object` одной строкой, **сразу с присвоением значений**?

```
Object[] obj = new Object[4];
obj[0] = new Object(205);
obj[1] = new Object(206);
obj[2] = new Object(207);
obj[3] = new Object(208);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object[] obj = new Object[]{new Object(20), new Object(20), new Object(20), new Object(20)};
```

Comment: Какая необходимость пихать все в одну строку? Оригинальный вариант легко было прочитать, а то, что ты сейчас написал - говнокод, который читается с трудом.

Comment: 1) Если это говнокод, т.е выражаясь нормальным языком, написан некорректно,  значит где-то должен существовать нормальный код. Раскройте наши незрящие глаза, приведите нам такой пример. 2) Если человек интересуется о способе записи в одну строку, следовательно у его возникла такая потребность. Логично, правда? 3) Читается с трудом, правда? Кому читается с трудом? Логика понятна? Тебе и только тебе, так что никому не интересно, как тебе это читается. Или где-то прописано, что в одну строку писать нельзя данный пример?!